# Want to send mail on each retry failure for REST post request

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-retry

I am running a test application to make a http POST submission to 3rd party REST endpoint and implemented retry using advice. I have used basic requesthandleradvice with simpleretryplicy and backoffpolicy set as exponential.how to call a method that sends mail on each retry failure. Example to do it would be great.

Here is how it worked for me . Thanks @artem for quick reply:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
                <property name="backOffPolicy">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                        <property name="initialInterval">
                            <value type="java.lang.Long">#{new Long('${initialRetryInterval}')}</value>         <!-- in milliSeconds -->
                         </property>
                        <property name="multiplier">
                            <value type="java.lang.Double">#{new Double('${retryExpMultiplier}')}</value>
                         </property>
                        <property name="maxInterval">
                         <value type="java.lang.Long">#{new Long('${.maxRetryInterval}')}</value>

             <!-- in milliSeconds -->
                     </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="retryPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts">
                        <value type="java.lang.Integer">#{new Integer('${maxRetryAttempts}')}</value>
                     </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="listeners">
                <bean class="com.example.listeners.SampleRetryListener"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` can be supplied with the `RetryTemplate`, which, in turn, can be supplied with the:

```
/**
 * Register an additional listener.
 *
 * @param listener the {@link RetryListener}
 * @see #setListeners(RetryListener[])
 */
public void registerListener(RetryListener listener) {
```

And the last one has this:

```
/**
 * Called after every unsuccessful attempt at a retry.
 * 
 * @param context the current {@link RetryContext}.
 * @param callback the current {@link RetryCallback}.
 * @param throwable the last exception that was thrown by the callback.
 * @param <T> the return value
 * @param <E> the exception to throw
 */
<T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable);
```

You can implement this method and send a `Message` to the `MessageChannel`, which has a `MailSendingMessageHandler` as a subscriber.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try this. I believe it should work. Will update soon